# Does letting the Conductor or DJ Grooves win change anything?

Tags: a-hat-in-time

In chapter 2 of A Hat in Time, does it change anything to let the Conductor or DJ Grooves win the battle for best film?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The changes are (mostly) purely cosmetic.

**The following assumes that you have completed Chapter 2 (including the boss fight), and will not use spoilers.**

---

- Award Ceremony: the winner will thank you and give you the time piece.
- Boss fight: the winner will fight against you, the loser will support you.

  - [Video of DJ Grooves fight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpVDPAczL4o&t=338s)
  - [Video of Conductor fight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpVDPAczL4o&t=728s)

Aside from that, there is not much difference. Both the Conductor and DJ Grooves have the same lines (except the Conductor calls you "*lassy*" and DJ Grooves uses "*darling*"). The boss fight remains identical, and even the winner's reason to fight you is exactly the same.

Answer (score -2):

The main change that depends on the winner of the Annual Bird Movie Awards is the dialog during the boss fight.

Comment: It changes more than just the dialogue. It changes who you fight as the chapter boss